# Handlebars templates in HAML using Ember.js

Tags: haml, ember.js

I'm looking for a way to write my Handlebars templates using HAML, in a Ember.js application embedded in a Rails 3.2 project.

Handlebars is 1.0.rc.1, require'd from ember-rails gem 0.7.0
Ember is 1.0.pre-90-g60e3c05

Anyway, my template now looks like that :

```
<div id="container">
  This is my test
</div>
```

I'd like it to be like this :

```
#container
  This is my test
```

BTW, I'v seen James Harton's [Hamlbars](https://github.com/jamesotron/hamlbars) but I could not figure out how to make it work. It kept outputing `Ember.TEMPLATES["templates/choose_resort"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile("This is my test");` instead of the intended :

```
<div id="container">
  This is my test
</div>
```

(even the div block is missing in the what-seems-to-be-uncompiled-code returned)

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hamlbars works for me - it outputs JS (as you mention yourself), so you should name the file .js.hamlbars and just include it in your manifest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the new [Emblem.js](https://github.com/machty/emblem.js). It's closer to Slim than HAML but cleanest you'll get if you're fond of indented templating languages and Ember.js.

And it is the one recommended by Ember.js [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a github project called  [Hamlbars](https://github.com/jamesotron/hamlbars). It looks like a great project I have not used it in a project yet but it looks promising.

this:

```
= hb 'App.widgetController.title'
```

will render:

```
{{App.widgetController.title}}
```

and this:

```
%ul.authors
  = hb 'each authors' do
  %li<
    = succeed ',' do
      = hb 'lastName'
      = hb 'firstName'
```

will render to

```
<ul class="authors">
  {{#each authors}}
    <li>{{lastName}}, {{firstName}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I took a look I'm sure it is just what you are looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

How to install hamlbars in three steps: [guide](https://coderwall.com/p/ypsaxq)